# Como salvar os dados na memória interna de um dispositivo Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou escrevendo arquivos na memória externa do dispositivo, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
File arquivo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+ nomeArquivo.getText().toString() + ".txt");
```

Estou escrevendo o arquivo na memória externa do celular certo? Então se o celular não tiver cartão de memória eu não conseguirei salvar meus dados. 
O que fazer neste caso para salvar os dados na memória interna do dispositivo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa, vale uma lida na documentação oficial do [Android sobre como salvar arquivos.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Para salvar na memória interna, usamos o método **openFileOutput()** passando como parâmetros o nome do arquivo e o modo/permissão.

As permissões podem ser privadas e púublicas.

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("nome do arquivo",MODE_WORLD_READABLE)
```

O méotodo **openFileOutput()** retorna uma instância de **FileOutputStream**, logo, você recebe um objeto FileInputStream. Depois disso, você pode chamar o métpdp de escrita para escrever os dados no arquivo:

```
String str = "data";
fOut.write(str.getBytes());
fOut.close();
```

Para ler o arquivo:

```
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput('nome do arquivo');
```

Classe de exemplo:

```
package com.example.storage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText et;
   private String data;
   private String file = "arquivo";
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      et = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText1));

   }

   public void save(View view){
      data = et.getText().toString();
      try {
         FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
         fOut.write(data.getBytes());
         fOut.close();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public void read(View view){
      try{
         FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
         int c;
         String temp="";
         while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
         }
         et.setText(temp);
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file read",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }catch(Exception e){

      }
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: O caminho absoluto de um arquivo na memória interna pode ser dado por: `String caminhoAbsolutoDoArquivo = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + nomeDoArquivo;`. Daí você usa por exemplo em: `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(caminhoAbsolutoDoArquivo);`

Comment: Ok, obrigado Piovezan!

Comment: Victor Mendonça funcionou aqui direitinho! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() não quer dizer o diretamente para o cartão de memória micro SD, aquele que você pode trocar por outro, basicamente esse comando retorna uma pasta de armazenamento de grande capacidade compartilhado por todos os apps.

Mais informações em: *http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()*

Para ler/gravar no external sdcard, neste caso o cartão de memoria, você tem que verificar se o caminho "/mnt/extSdCard" existe.

Comment: Ah sim! Entendi Clebao, obrigado!