# O PrintWriter não funciona no Android?

Tags: android

Estou tentando executar este código, mas ele não funciona, da erro no try{}, no Java ele funciona perfeitamente.

```
public void criatxt(){

      String texto = "XXX";

      try{
         PrintWriter arq = new PrintWriter("meudocumento.txt");
         System.out.println("Salvou");
         arq.print(texto);
         arq.close();
      }
      catch(Exception er){
         er.printStackTrace();  
         System.out.println("Salvou: "+ er.getStackTrace());
      }
}
```

O erro que da no Exception é esse: Ljava.lang.StackTraceElemente;@xxxxxxx

Comment: `PrintWriter` funciona normalmente no Android. Se está dando erro no `try`, informe na sua pergunta qual é o erro que está dando. Se for uma mensagem no logcat, poste o texto da mensagem.

Comment: da esse erro: Ljava.lang.StackTraceElemente;@xxxxxxx

Comment: Esse erro é porque você imprimiu `er.getStackStrace()`. Troque por `er.getMessage()` ou `er.getClass().getName()` e diga o que está sendo impresso. Mas note que antes disso você está chamando `er.printStackTrace()` e a exceção completa está sendo impressa no logcat e isso é o que precisamos aqui, talvez você apenas não esteja conseguido achar.

Comment: acho q o arquivo está sendo salvo em um lugar que não pode, você sabe como faço para criar esse txt em um lugar específico como o C:?

Comment: Ele não está sendo salvo. Está tentando salvar mas está dando uma exceção, tanto que imprimiu `er.getStackTrace()` que retornou `Ljava.lang.StackTraceElemente;@xxxxxxx`. Queremos saber qual é a exceção.

Comment: Se quiser salvar em um lugar específico, veja [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5320/como-salvar-os-dados-na-mem%C3%B3ria-interna-de-um-dispositivo-android/5330).